# PHP stopped working after MacOS update to High Sierra

Tags: php, macos-high-sierra, localserver

I recently upgraded to High-Sierra and now my local server won't run PHP (code shows it as text)

To try and solve the issue I removed all php versions with homebrew and installed php 7.2 using homebrew. But the issue remains.

I don't see any error in the local server log files.

P.S.
I do not see attempted to add

```
LoadModule php7_module   /usr/local/opt/php72/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

But the path seems to be wrong since I get an error..

Comment: that will be solved in your httpd server configurations. You must have a mime type for .php files, which probably got nuked when installing sierra.

Comment: can you pls share more details?

Comment: there is a ton of q/a here about why php is echoed as is (ie not executed). I gave you the most (by far) likely reason.

Comment: yes, thanks, but I'm not sure how to actually do this..

Comment: **[This is the ultimate guide](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions)** for configuring httpd and php on osx sierra. Read it carefully, you should be able to relegate the shipped version  to obivion without removing it

Comment: Try adding `Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf` to your `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file. At the end. Inside that included folder there should be a file called `php7.conf`. Then restart apache and try again. That's what macOS Server does, anyway. Furthermore, `LoadModule php7_module   /usr/local/opt/php72/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so` is commented with a `#`, at least in my working configuration. Except that the path is different: `#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to reinstall XCode Command Line Tools and this solved the issue